# load external page in ionic component after form submit

Tags: angular, ionic3

i want load my action page in ionic component when submitting my form ,
now when i submit my form it take me away in the action URL

i'm using ionic 3 and angular 4

my form code :

```
   <ion-row>
        <form #f method="post" action="https://my.url.com"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="clientid" [(ngModel)]="clientid" />
            <input type="hidden" name="trantype" [(ngModel)]="trantype" />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" [(ngModel)]="amount" />
        </form>   
    </ion-row>
```

my submit function :

```
submit(form){
  let data = {
    "clientid": form.clientid.value,
    "trantype": form.trantype.value,
    "amount": form.amount.value,
  }
  this.paiementService.getHash(data, this.token).subscribe(
    data => {
      form.hash.value = data;
      form.submit();
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: where is your submit button in HTML file?

Comment: i'm submit the form using the function after clicking in anther button : <ion-item><button ion-button block (click)="payer(f)"><ion-icon name="card"> </ion-icon></button></ion-item>

Comment: and that url referes to you action page?

Comment: it not "https://my.url.com" ,  i change it but i'm sure that the action page work 100%

Comment: I mean if it is a page that is available in your app then instead of this way you can redirect it by using navctrl.push as it is best way.

Comment: no its not in my page ,  its an external page !

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Same issue